# algebra need help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ x=-4$ then $(x+3)(x+4)=?$

I cannot figure this out. I have been out of school for over 15 yrs! If anyone can please give me a detailed explanation, I would appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Here's a hint:  If $x=-4$, what is $x+4=?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It helps us help you if you give us an attempt at the problem. We can tell you exactly where you're going wrong and help you avoid this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If $x=-4$, then you should substitute $-4$ into

$$(x+3)(x+4)$$

to get

$$ (x+3) = (-4 + 3)= -1$$
$$(x+4)=(-4+4)=0$$

and then multiply $(-1)(0)$. What do you get when you multiply $-1\times 0$?

Answer (score 2):

If $x=-4$ then $x+4=0$, so $x+4$ times anything is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This expression $(x+3)(x+4)$ means actually $(x+3) \cdot (x+4)$. Read this carefully: The $\cdot$ is a symbol for a [multiplication sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign). It's hidden, because people who do mathematics are lazy people. They like to make it tight.

If we were to put $-4$ instead of $x$ inside the expression $(x+3)(x+4)$, then we need to replace the occurrence of each and every $x$ inside the expression $(x+3)(x+4)$ with $-4$, because $x=-4$.

We plug in a $-4$ for every $x$ we see, because $x$ and $-4$ are equal.

We substitute $-4$ for $x$.

Then we get: $$(\color{red}{x}+3)(\color{red}{x}+4)=(\color{red}{-4}+3)\cdot(\color{red}{-4}+4) = (-1) \cdot (0)=-1\cdot 0=0$$

Multiplying $-1$ by $0$ in the last step yields $0$, [because anything times zero is zero](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/multiply-by-zero.html) and for example [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-zero-multiplied-by-any-number-equal-to-zero) you can read more about multiplication by zero and [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/positive-negative-integers.html) you can read about using the number line to add and subtract numbers.

$x$ is a great achievement of Humanity. Anything you don't yet know, just call it $x$ and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It'a all about of making acts of calculation visible.  Take doubling, e.g.  Doubling as itself is invisible, but no one would deny that it exists.  "Nowadays" mathematicians use "placeholders" to visualize that act by writing $2\cdot x$.  Now in that context $x$ is not considered as a letter in our alphabet but shall represent any number.  One could also write $2\cdot\square$ instead and that "expression" $2x$ is a representation for the act(ion) of doubling.

The "expression" $(x+3)(x+4)$ represents a bit more complex act: Think of a number.  Build two new numbers by increasing that  number by $3$ and by $4$.  Then multiply both.

You may do this with any number.  If you choose $-4$ for that number, the two new numbers will be $-1$ and $0$, hence their product equals zero.